# JavaScript Minification and Optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, include, dependencies

I'm a little confused about how to best optimize my JavaScript and script dependencies.

Let's say I have a script named `foo.js` and a script named `bar.js`.

`foo.js` requires `jquery ui-sortable`, and `bar.js` requires `jquery ui-datepicker`.

There are only a handful of pages on my site that require both `foo.js` and `bar.js`.

Do I compile everything into a single file and minify it, and call it on every page, even though only a portion of the functions are ever needed at a time?

Or would it be better to call them separately, only when needed, and make the additional http requests in these instances?

Is there a better option I'm missing?

Comment: It's a tradeoff.  You don't want separate resources on every single page so the local browser can never use caching.  But, you don't want to over burden every single page with an accumulation of stuff not used on that page.  So, you have to find a happy medium and how to choose for any given page depends upon a bunch of things.  There is no absolute answer one way or the other.  If practical, you may consider a small number of separate minimized files that can be effectively cached and use the ones appropriate for a given page with effort spent optimizing for the most used pages.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would prefer calling the required resources only when needed. You will not have the burden to manage each and every page with unnecessary imports and will improve the load time of your website.

Answer (score 0):

It is really a matter of trade off specifically related to your application.

First, you can consider using [jQuery from a CDN](https://code.jquery.com/), this will allowed to increases the chance that there will be a cache-hit (reducing the amount of bandwidth used by your server) and it ensures that the user will get a geographically close response.

Regarding your custom code, the best way to measure the impact of an optimization is to run tests for your app. Try setting up an A/B test and study your users' experience with your site.

Generally, in my opinion, using in production a unique minified file (which result in a single HTTP request) is usually a suitable solution but it really depends of the size of your code base.